# Many selectors & add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I'm using jQuery to handle unsupported selectors in IE7 & 8 (mostly, `:nth-child` and `:last-child`). I've read that `addClass` is more performant than using jQuery's `css` method, so I'm refactoring my JS to do just that.

What's the best approach to add the same class to multiple (sometimes many!) different selectors? Is it safe to just throw them all into the same statement and use addClass at the end of the list?

For instance:

```
$('.selector1:nth-child(3),
   .diff-selector2:last-child,
   #another-selector:nth-child(2),
   tr.highlighted td:last-child,
   h2.job-title:last-child').addClass('fallback-class');
```

Is there a limit or a point at which that list of selectors becomes slow? Should I create variables for those selector lists? Is there a better approach?

Final note: using Selectivizr, unfortunately, was making IE7 come to a halt. That's why I've decided to use the above approach.

Comment: I assume that adding a common class to teach of the controls in question is not an option?

Comment: Just refactor your html so you never need to use those selectors, which are incredibly slow. Without cache, for each element that are checked for nth child, that element's parent's all child elements need to be traversed through.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a case where I don't really have access to the HTML and where I do, it's stuff that is controlled by a CMS (Drupal).

Comment: Add the html in your question then

Comment: Let's see if I can get away with not posting the HTML - these pages are huge & the site's not live yet. I don't mean to be snarky with my response, I just would rather not post the actual HTML and typing out a bunch of fake HTML probably wouldn't help very much.

Based on your first response, Esailija, you're suggesting that I should either try to first select by an ID or by the nth-child's parent element and then use something like `filter` or `find` and also cache those selectors in a var?

Answer (score 2):

2 ways come to my mind

1) u can set a common class to your elements and add them a class

```
<p class="addThis">1</p>
<p>2</p>
<span class="addThis">3</span>
<a>4</a>
<p>5</p>
<a class="addThis">6</a>

$('.addThis').addClass('fallback-class'); //1,3,6 will be added classes
```

2) u can use parent/children method

```
<p>
    <a>1</a>
    <span>2</span><!-- wont be added class -->
</p>
<p>
    <a>3</a>
</p>
<a>3</a><!-- wont be added class -->
<p>4</p><!-- wont be added class -->

$('p').children('a').addClass('fallback-class');
//this will adds class which got "a" selector inside "p"

$('a').parent('p').addClass('fallback-class');
//this will adds class "p" selector which got children "a"
```